# .NET Core Web API : how to access user claims without using the HttpContextAccessor?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I have a .NET Core 3+ Web API with custom authentication. I refer to it in my startup like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme;
}).AddCustomAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.AuthKey = "custom";
   });
```

My custom `AuthenticationHandler` puts various claims into the `Authentication` ticket. Code snippets for brevity:

```
public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    ...
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("custom");

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "someUserId"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "someUserName"));

        var identities = new List<ClaimsIdentity> { identity };
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identities), Options.Scheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to access these claims from the controllers. .NET Core 3 doesn't provide the `User` or `HttpContext` anymore. I found that adding the `HttpContextAccessor` from startup would give access from the controllers.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
... 
public TestController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor) { }
```

From the injected `httpContextAccessor` I can get to the claims, but I'm finding this method a bit tedious. I have to inject it in every controller (they all need the claim information). Is there not an easier way I can make these claims available to all my controllers?

Or was it .NET Core's intent to access claims in this way?

Comment: FWIW, that's exactly how we are accessing the claims

Comment: Controllers have `HttpContext` on themself, why inject `IHttpContextAccessor` there anyway ? You only need `IHttpContextAccessor` inject on other service that's not inherited from `ControllerBase`.

Comment: ASP.NET Core's `ControllerBase`  **DOES** have a `.User` property - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - this should give you access to the currently logged in user as a `ClaimsPrincipal`

Comment: As mentioned in the attached link, both HttpContext and it's user properties are only available once inside the action method. My problem was that I was trying to access this from the constructor. In that case, you do need to inject the HttpContextAccessor to expose those values.